# Method stops being called

Tags: java, libgdx

I made a method that creates an object every time is called, the spawning will stop when a boolean variable is equal to true, but when I set the variable back to false the method that will spawn my characters is not called anymore, I don't understand since it's on the render method so it should update every frame.

```
   public void update() {
            deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            timer += 1 * deltaTime;

            if(endGame==false) {  //when the game starts it works.
                if (timer >= rTime) {
                    newEnemy0();//this is the method for spawning
                    timer -= rTime;
                    rTime = rFloat.nextInt(3) + 1 * 1f;
                    rPosition1 = rFloat.nextInt(700) + 1;
                }
            }/*when a certain thing happen endGame==true, then when I click a button it will be back to false but when I put it back to false nothing happens*/


//this is the newRnemy method basically it just creates a new sprite using pools.
 public void newEnemy0(){
        Sprite enemy= Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        enemy.setSize(80,80);
        enemy.setPosition(rPosition1, 150);
        enemies.add(enemy);
    }



 //I just realized that endGame doesn't go back to false when I click a button:
 playButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
           @Override
           public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
               enemyObj.endGame=false;
               System.out.println(enemyObj.endGame);
               return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
           }
       });// this code is not updated every frame.
```

Comment: You may need to post the place where this method is being called.

Comment: Are you setting the `endGame` boolean from a different thread??? In that case you should use a `volatile boolean`...

Comment: Note that during the time `endGame` is true, the timer is continuing to go up, so if you left it for a few minutes and then resumed the game, it would spawn many enemies within a second right at the beginning of the game. But I think your problem may be related to your `newEnemy0()` method. Share that code.

Comment: The `rTime` (1-2-3) is a quite small value; is the timing in seconds? Further assumptions: deltaTime and timer are doubles, deltaTime not 0.